# Using if function to set new values for midpoint etc Binary search

Tags: python, arrays, search, binary

Hi so im trying to do a binary search which finds a value that im searching for. I'm having trouble with a part of it though. First of all it divides the array by 2 to find the midpoint and looks to see if the midpoint is = the value if not it prints not found. If its not found i want it to to do these calculation.

```
if value < MP: 
    UB = MP-1
    LB = len(array) - len (array)
    print ("ubperbound is" ,UB)
else:
    UB = len(array)-1
    LB =MP + 1
```

So if the Value is less than Midpoint , it should take away 1 from the original mid point and make that the Upper band and the lower band will be 0 however if its more than midpoint , Lower band should be midpoint + 1 and Upper band should be the array length.

However im struggling to get this to work :/ it just wont work . some guidance would be helpful. thanks

```
array = [9,7,8,5,3,6,4,2,3,1,10]
array.sort()
print (array)
index = 0
value = 40
MP = int((len(array)-1) /2)
SB = False 

UB = int(len(array)-1)
LB = index

print ("Midpoint is",array[MP])
print ("Upperbound is" ,UB)
print ("Lowerbound is",LB)

if MP == value:
     print("found")
else:
     print("Value is not the midpoint")
```

Comment: "it just won't work" is not a problem description.  When I run this, it works just fine ... as far as it goes.  I get midpoint as 5, bounds as 0 and 10, and that the value (4) wasn't found.  This is correct for the first iteration, which is all you've coded.  What's the problem?

Comment: You need a loop that keeps selecting new midpoints until the item is found or you run out of items to search.

Comment: yes it works , the problem is i added the bit on top which finds out if the value is smaller or larger than midpoint and if it is it either adds 1 or minus one from UB etc to go to the other side of the value. But it dnt work :(